# Smoothness of flows of time-varying ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

Let $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{d+1}$ be open and let $f:U \to \mathbb{R}^d$ be a $C^k$ map ($1 \leq k \leq \infty$). I want to prove that the flow of the **time-varying ODE** $\dot x(t) = f(t,x(t))$ with initial condition $x(t_0) =x_0$ is smooth.

That is, the map $(t,t_0, x_0) \mapsto x(t)$ has open domain in $\mathbb{R}^{d+2}$, and is $C^k$.

I know that this is true for time-invariant ODEs (that is, the map $(t,x_0) \mapsto x(t)$ has open domain and is $C^k$), but I cannot find a proof for time-varying ODEs.

Can anyone help me with a proof or by providing a reference?
Thank you!

Comment: [Lee's book](https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Smooth-Manifolds-John-Lee-ebook/dp/B00DGEQEVQ)  treats time-dependent flows

Comment: First of all, presumably $n=d+1$? Can you not think of the vector field instead on $U\times\Bbb R$, incorporating $t$ as one of your coordinates. Let $y=(x,t)$, and then $f(t,x(t))$ can be written simply as $g(y(t))$. And what is $\dot y$?

Comment: @Ted Shifrin $n=d$, sorry for confusion.